# A Button that changes images android

Tags: java, android

i have an app set for tests anyway i have a button an pics when i press the button the pics should keep changing then reset to first one and so on that code below gives explanation

```
        Button chngbutn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Bchangepic);
     iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVviewer);

    chngbutn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int change=0;

            if(change==0){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.image);
                change++;
            }
            else if (change==1){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageb);
                change=2;
            }else if (change==2){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagec);
                change=0;
            }
```

the iv is outside the oncreate brackets..

but the problem with this coding it changes the image once only and stucks on imageb

and before that i tried the switch statement 
using the code below

```
            switch (change){

            case 1:
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.spacey_b);
                change++;
                break;
            case 2:
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.spacey_c);
                change++;
                break;
            case 3:
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.spacey);
                change=0;
                break;                  
            }
```

but in switch it doesn't do anything any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `int change = 0;` should be outside `onCreate` too or else you will get `0` value always.